# Have there been any ruling salt son?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

A [salt son](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Salt_son) is the son of an ironborn and a [salt wife](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Salt_wife). According to both "salt son" and "salt wife" wiki page, a salt son can inherit, even if they are behind [rock wife](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rock_wife). However, I don't remember any mention of a famous salt son, ruling the Iron Island or even a major House like Harlaw, Drumm or Goodbrother ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can’t find reference to who succeeds Dalton Greyjoy, The Red Kraken, but it was a salt son as he never took a rock wife.

> The Red Kraken had never taken a rock wife.** His closest heirs were his salt sons**, young boys fathered on various of his salt wives. Within hours of his death, a bloody struggle for succession broke out. And even before the battles began on Old Wyk and Pyke, the smallfolk of Fair Isle rose up and slaughtered those ironmen who still remained amongst them.
>   In 134 AC, Lady Johanna Lannister took her revenge for all that the Red Kraken had inflicted on her and hers. With her own fleets destroyed, she persuaded Ser Leo Costayne, the aged lord admiral of the Reach, to deliver her swordsmen to the Iron Islands. Embroiled in their own war of succession, the ironborn were taken unawares. Thousands of men, women, and children were put to the sword, scores of villages and hundreds of longships put to the torch. Ultimately Costayne was slain in battle, his host largely scattered and destroyed. Only a portion of his fleet (laden with the spoils of war, including many tons of grain and salt fish) returned to Lannisport...but **amongst the highborn captives they brought back to Casterly Rock was one of the Red Kraken's salt sons**. Lady Johanna had him gelded and made him her son's fool. "A fine fool he proved," Archmaester Haereg observes, "yet not half so foolish as his father."
>    <sub>The World of Ice and Fire,- The Iron Islands: The Red Kraken</sub>

Comment: Nice catch, even if nothing guaranty that the successor of the Red Kraken is his son, as his brothers could also claim the throne

Comment: @Kepotx True but it's the closest I could find :)

Comment: `Lady Johanna had him gelded`... ♪ ♪A lion still has claws, and mine are long, and sharp my lord, just ask Red Kraken's son ♪ ♪